# SIP Client library for python

Tags: python, sip, voip

A few days ago, I was given the following task: to implement the receiving/creating of calls using the sip client. I started by looking for a library for the sip client, preferably in python, I use an external server from a popular service. After several hours of searching, I found the pyvoip library. At first glance, it had all the necessary functionality, but ..
Having started writing code and trying the first launches, it turned out that the library does not support DIGEST authorization and OPTIONS requests. After looking for solutions in the github issues of the library, I found a solution - install the dev version!(LOL)
She already hadn't "missing parts", but there were even more problems with her - the code was incredibly raw. I fixed the main problems and still connected to the sip server, but again another disappointment .. The connection with the server does not hold and still has a lot of problems with the code

After 5 days of constant debugging, testing, and fixing someone else's code, I was drained and started looking for other solutions, but I still couldn't find them, so I'm writing here, maybe someone has dealt with such tasks.

Thanks in advance for your reply!